# Sorting function using java

Tags: java, sorting

I am writing a java application.

```
  ArrayList<int[]> list = new ArrayList<int[]>();

  double[] array = new double[10];
```

I have written a function to sort the array and sort list based on the array sort.
But my function doesnt work correctly.

```
  public void sort() {
    int n = array.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        double m = array[i];
        int[] d = list.get(i);
        int j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (array[j] > m))
        {
            array[j+1] = array[j--];
            list.set(j+1, list.get(j--));
        }
        array[j+1]=m;
        list.set(j+1, d);
    }
}
```

It has  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in line :

```
          list.set(j+1, list.get(j--));
```

How can I solve the problem and sort the list based on the sort of array?

Comment: Where is this line in your code?                  choromosomes.set(j+1, choromosomes.get(j--));

Comment: The line the error is from isn't it the code you've posted. Can you show that code?

Answer (score 2):

When `i==1`, `j` is initially 0.

Assuming `array[0] > array[1]`, the if block is entered, and after:

```
array[j+1] = array[j--];
```

`j == -1`, so you can't use it to index `list`. The second decrement looks suspicious too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link has everything you need: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/70sorting.html

Basically to sort an array you'll use java.util.Arrays' sort method and for ArrayList you'll use java.util.Collections' sort method.